# How to make post title to appear after an image?

Tags: custom-post-types

Normally, the post title is at the top of the page in wordpress. I would like the post title to appear after adding an image to my blog.

I have already created a custom post template. I would like your help to know what code needs to be added to that template PHP file to make this possible.

You can have a look at this blog created by me. I would like to have something exactly like this. below the post title, if the date of post published, author name can appear it would be great.
https://pimpthat.site/intercom-inspiration-blog-style/

Comment: This would go a lot better if you included the code from your template, that was someone could show you were to insert the code for the thumbnail, title and author.  (The author would probably have to be added in the entry-meta tag that lists the date and categories, but that varies from theme to theme and you may want to output the entire thing yourself.)

Answer (score 0):

`get_the_post_thumbnail()` and `get_the_title()` have to be switched in order in the PHP file.